# Rails: Why can't you set an association to nil in a where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I have photos that belong to collections and users. Photos always belong to a user, but may not be assigned to a collection.

In my controller, this works perfectly:

```
@collection_photos = Photo.where( :collection => @collection, :user => current_user )
```

However, this fails...

```
@other_photos = Photo.where( :collection => nil, :user => current_user )
```

...but this works:

```
@other_photos = Photo.where( :collection_id => nil, :user => current_user )
```

When collection is set to nil I get this error message: `No attribute named 'collection' exists for table photos`.

If I pass an object, it knows to search for `collection_id` from the symbol `:collection`, but if I don't pass an object it doesn't seem to be aware of the association.

Am I understanding this correctly? Could anyone explain a little better why `:collection=>nil` doesn't work?

Comment: Great question. I had to go deep into the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use pass in the conditions into ActiveRecord, it actually tries to analyze the objects that you passed in, is it a string? an array? a hash? and what's in the string, array or hash?

and in your case, a hash, so it's trying to analyze what's in the hash, in the first statement (which works), you passed in a model instance as the value, so it tries to find if there are any associations that mapped to the key your specified and voila, it found it and everything works as planned

in the second case, you passed in nil as the value, now, ActiveRecord sees that it's a nil object, so it decided that it's not an association. note that it doesn't look at the key, but it only looked at the value, thus it tries to find if there's any column that mapped to the key, but it couldn't find, returning an error

in the last case, you passed in nil as the value, same thing, it tried to find a column which mapped to :collection_id, thus it passed in nil as the value in the SQL statement, and it returned successfully

so it's just an unfortunate considerations taken by ActiveRecord that makes the second case not working =)

hope this clarifies! =D

Comment: So, this is a good explanation of the code, it definitely validates my understanding just from reading the code on the link Jordan posted. As a follow up question, can you think of a straightforward way to patch this? I'd be interested in enabling a more consistent syntax here unless there's a major reason not to.

Comment: actually i wouldn't recommend you to patch the code as it poses a few traps for your project, e.g. when you update rails, when you are working with a few programmers, when you look at sample codes from other programmers, etc. there's just too many catch to want to alter the default behavior provided by a framework... for me your third way of doing suffice and it's actually clearer than wanting to do it the first way... just my opinions =)

Comment: and further more in your case you are trying to analyze the value when it's nil, which meant that for every query finding columns that are nil, you are imposing some overheads since you have to check if there's a association in the column... not sure if you get me on this though

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's like the famous rails **.find vs .find_by_id**.

**.find** is designed to throw an exception if it cannot find any association.

where as **.find_by_id** will just return nil if doesn't find any association.

so in your **.where** statement, when you search for the collection it's probably treating that like a **.find** and when you search by collection_id it will return **nil** just like **.find_by_id** does if it can't find any associated collection.

I'm not sure how these two methods differ in Activerecord's inner workings, but they are designed to react differently to nil results.

Comment: That's probably a good guess, thanks! I would be interested to know if anyone actually *knows* why it doesn't work though.

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer is in [`ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder.build_from_hash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb). There is a case statement in there that checks the class of each value in the hash, and it specifically looks for `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: hey indeed! was trying to find the link but couldn't get it, one up =)

Comment: Thanks. It took some spelunking at Github

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see how it works. As a follow up question (same as I asked Staelen), can you think of a straightforward way to patch this? I'd be interested in enabling a more consistent syntax here unless there's a major reason not to.

Comment: It's too late for me to really wrap my head around what's happening in there. A good starting point would be in `when Class`. You'll need to check if `column` is `reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name).include?(column.to_sym) and value.nil?` then figure out what `attribute.eq(value.name)` and `attribute.in(value.arel.ast)` are doing. I'd test for a performance hit though, as I'm not sure about the impact of `reflect_on_all_associations`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to no longer be an issue in Rails 4. For instance the following code

```
@other_photos = Photo.where( :collection => nil, :user => User.first )
```

would run

```
User Load (Xms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Photo Load (Xms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos"  WHERE "photos"."collection_id" IS NULL AND "photos"."user_id" = 1
```

*Tested in Rails 4.1.1